# Type mismatch when creating List of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to part the `mainList`arraylist to 3 sublist Arraylist and then add it as sublist in other arraylist `mainSublist` but I am getting this error:
 How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

> 1)-Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to ArrayList
>
> 2) -The method add(RootCreator) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

**Code:**

```
    ArrayList<RootCreator> mainList = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();
    for (String key : names) {
        RootCreator rootcreat = join_line(path, key);
        mainList.add(rootcreat);
    }
    ArrayList<RootCreator> mainSublist = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();

    for(int i= 0 ; i < mainList.size(); i++){
        int index = i*3;    
        //the error 1 is here       
        ArrayList<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
         //error 2 is here
        mainSublist.add(sublist);
    }
```

Comment: What do you think the errors mean? What is the return type of `subList`? What is the parameter type (expected argument type) of `add`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Mao but when I change it to map I am getting `Cannot instantiate the type List<RootCreator>` ? how to fix that?

Comment: use this for error 1- 
List<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
error 2 -
mainSublist.addAll(sublist);

Answer (score 1):

All List are not ArrayList, so when you use sublist you get a generic List. On the other hand, the method to add a collection to another collection is addAll instead add.

```
List<RootCreator> mainList = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();
for (String key : names) {
    RootCreator rootcreat = join_line(path, key);
    mainList.add(rootcreat);
}
List<RootCreator> mainSublist = new ArrayList<RootCreator>();

for(int i= 0 ; i < mainList.size(); i++){
    int index = i*3;    
    //the error 1 is here       
    List<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
     //error 2 is here
    mainSublist.addAll(sublist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `subList` method returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`, and you cannot assign a `List` to an `ArrayList`.  In fact, the `List` returned by the `subList` method is not an `ArrayList`.

If it needs to be an `ArrayList`, then create an `ArrayList` out of the sub list.

```
ArrayList<RootCreator> sublist = new ArrayList<>(mainList.subList(0, index));
```

If you just need a `List`, then make `sublist` a `List` instead.

```
List<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
```

You can't add an `ArrayList<RootCreator>` to an `ArrayList<RootCreator>`; you must add a `RootCreator`.  If you want to add the elements of `sublist` to another list, then use the `addAll` method.

```
mainSublist.addAll(sublist);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's look at the two errors here:

```
//the error 1 is here       
ArrayList<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
```

This is telling you that you're trying to assign something of the type `List` to a variable that's declared as an `ArrayList`. While an `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`, it doesn't work both ways - you can assign an `ArrayList` to a `List`, but not vice versa. So let's change your declaration:

```
//the error 1 was here, but fixed.        
List<RootCreator> sublist = mainList.subList(0, index);
```

The second one is slightly different:

```
//error 2 is here
mainSublist.add(sublist);
```

Here, you've got a list defined to hold items of the type `RootCreator` - but you're not adding `RootCreator` items, you're adding a list of them. So if you want to have the list *hold* other lists, you need to specify that when you create it:

```
ArrayList<List<RootCreator>> mainSublist = new ArrayList<List<RootCreator>>();
```

But, if you're trying to just keep a single list and want to add everything from the sublists, then instead, change your code to:

```
//error 2 was here, but Fixed
mainSublist.addAll(sublist);
```